# Flashed addonsu-arm-signed.zip on LineageOS, still no root

Tags: rooting, nexus-5, titanium-backup, lineageos

I just installed LineageOS 14.1 using TWRP.

Then, following [this guide](http://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/download-supersuzp-and-su-removalzip.html) I downloaded [addonsu-arm-signed.zip](https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-14.1-arm-signed.zip) to my SD card and installed it, also using TWRP.

PROBLEM: Then I installed Titanium Backup from Play Store, an got this message:

[image]

Is there a mistake in my procedure?
Is there a missing step?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Settings.
2. Click on About phone and then tap 7 times on the Build number.
3. Navigate back, open Developer Options.
4. Tap Root Access.
5. Select `Apps` or `Apps and ADB`.

Now you have root and Titanium Backup finds it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just found I had to switch from ADB only to Apps and ADB. Not sure why, since the issue was with ADB itself.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//android.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.